# Is it an acceptable practice to disable AJAX when using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am building a mobile app that will be using local assets.  I am very new to web development but it seems like with using local assets I will not need to use AJAX as provided with jQuery and jQuery Mobile.  This application will also link to other external applications.

Is it acceptable to disable AJAX navigation for the entire app in this situation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can configure this as a broad setting in JQM, so I think it's totally acceptable. What is your biggest concern?

Comment: Mostly my concern is my lack of knowledge.  Trying to learn as much as i can but most tutorials assume the reader knows about AJAX and how it plays with other things.

Comment: AJAX took a while for me to wrap my head around it. For me, it was easier to work with when I understood that it is simply making an HTTP request that you control via JavaScript. The request will be successful or it will fail with an error, but you will get some sort of result. It can be used in many different ways. For web apps, it's really useful as you can make sections of your page interact with online APIs or scripts without changing the page. It makes for a stronger user experience.

Comment: Deciding when to use AJAX or be more traditional will depend on your personal coding style and the specific use case of your site or app. Google is a good example, you may remember when you would have to click "Google Search" button to start a search in the past. Now, as soon as you start typing, it changes the page and does lookups to help you more quickly get to the search you're trying to search for. Each keystroke executes AJAX, that looks up a fraction of a word, and returns a list of words or phrases that might align with what you're typing.